# CSS not centering text in box, instead goes to the right side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a problem with my code. I want the text to be centered at all devices. But it seems like its going to the right side of the box? Example, try to make the window smaller, you will see the text going to right side instead of being centered all the time.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
#box1 {
  background-color: rgba(55,190,239,0.6);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 105px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.1vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /*Gradient*/
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
 
  /*Transition*/
  -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
  transition: All 0.5s ease;
}

#box1:hover {
    background-color: rgba(55,190,239,0.9);
}
```

```html
<a href="/fastigheter/"><div id="box1">FASTIGHETER</div></a>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fg7xe9s9/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fg7xe9s9/

Comment: What are you using to view the page?  I tried it Chrome and Firefox and the text stayed in the center of my screen no matter how I re-sized the window.  All I see is white space in the code snippet, so I can't say if it looks any different from that.

Answer (score 1):

You need quit padding-left and right: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xowb31nL/)

```
#box1 {
  background-color: rgba(55,190,239,0.6);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 105px;
  padding-bottom: 105px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.1vh;
  font-weight: bold;

 /*Gradient*/
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

 /*Transition*/
-webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
transition: All 0.5s ease;
}

#box1:hover {
    background-color: rgba(55,190,239,0.9);
}
```